# IF function in Google Sheets (scripts) with dates (today)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

what could be wrong in these code?

```
 ...
 spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Daty'), true);
 var today = spreadsheet.getRange('B1').getValue()
 spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ZNC'), true);
 var changeday = spreadsheet.getRange('E2').getValue()
 var nrrej = spreadsheet.getRange('A2')
 if(nrrej!=="" && changeday<today)
 {Browser.msgBox("Info");
 }else{
 ...
```

Script does not take these conditions into consideration together. Separately it is OK.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

*You are comparing a [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) with a `string`*.

### How to fix it

The variables `today` and `changeday` are values. They are defined as `getRange('X').getValue()`. However, `nrrej` is a range and you are comparing it with a string (`""`). The best approach to check if a cell is blank is using the function [isBlank](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank). It returns `true` if the range is totally blank.

### Final code

```
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Daty'), true);
  var today = spreadsheet.getRange('B1').getValue()
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ZNC'), true);
  var changeday = spreadsheet.getRange('E2').getValue()
  var nrrej = spreadsheet.getRange('A2').isBlank()
  if (nrrej == false && changeday < today) {
    Browser.msgBox("Info");
  } else { }
```

### Some advice

- Use the [debugger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#use_the_debugger_and_breakpoints) to check the status of the variables before getting an error
- Use automatic indentation with `ctrl + shft + I`

### References

- [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Range: isBlank](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank)
- [Range: getValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)
- [Use the debugger and breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#use_the_debugger_and_breakpoints)

Comment: It is quite interesting, because if I checking on this:
var nrrej = spreadsheet.getRange('A2').getValue()
if (nrrej > "")
A script do not see that A2 is Blank. But if i delete .getValue() from A2 (nrrej) it see...

Comment: The best approach to check if a cell is blank is with the build-in function, check my update

Comment: Sth is wrong, becasue if nrrej and changeday are blank script is stopped. But if sth is in nrrej (changeday still blank) script run and when sth is in changeday (nrrej still blank) script run Today (B1) is formula =TODAY().

Comment: I have updated the code. I didn't check that you wrote `nrrej!==""`, so the new condition should be `nrrej == false` because `nrrej` is `true` if the cell is blank. If this doesn't solve it, could you give me some example data to test the code?